# Java reading and indexing large amount of files

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, spring-boot, apache-tika

I'm working on application that is supposed to read a large amount of files (test set is about 80.000 files). It then extracts the text from these files. The files can be anything from txt, pdf, docx, etc. and will be parsed using Apache Tika.

Once the text is extracted, it will be indexed in ElasticSearch to become searchable. Elastic has, thus far, not been a problem in this.

The server on which this application will run will have limited RAM (about 2GB)

### Current

The Tika implementation is as follows:

```
private static final int PARSE_STRING_LIMIT = 100000;
private static final AutoDetectParser PARSER_INSTANCE = new AutoDetectParser(PARSERS);
private static final Tika TIKA_INSTANCE = new Tika(PARSER_INSTANCE.getDetector(), PARSER_INSTANCE);

public String parseToString(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException, TikaException {
    try {
        return TIKA_INSTANCE.parseToString(inputStream, new Metadata(), PARSE_STRING_LIMIT);
    } finally {
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(inputStream); //should already be closed by parseToString.
    }
}
```

For each file, a document object is created and given the appropriate values for the ElasticSearch mapping. Text extraction is done as follows:

```
String text = TIKA_INSTANCE.parseToString(newBufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file)));
attachmentDocumentNew.setText(text);
text = null;
```

One more caveat is that this is a Spring-boot application which will eventually run as a server so it can be called upon whenever the index is necessary (and some other stuff, such as statistics).

The jar is run with the following VM arguments:

`java -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -XX:UseG1GC -jar <jar>`

### The problem

Whenever I start indexing the files, i get an `OutOfMemoryException`. I tried profiling it using VisualVM, but it's mostly char[] and byte[], which don't provide a lot of information. I am also not well versed in multithreading or profiling (I do neither at this point), since I only have 2 years of programming experience.

### The question

**How do I reduce the memory footprint of the application without crashing the indexing?**

Perhaps a more general question if the above is too specific:
**How do I reduce the memory usage when reading a large amounts of files?**

If you have experience building something like this, I'll also be open about any suggestions :)

### Edit

To clarify, I do **not** have to write much (any?) code for the Elasticsearch part of the application, since this is done using an existing library written by the people here.

Comment: Could you please provide more information about the indexing? Sample code and index structure would be very helpful.

Comment: @maestro Since this is for a company, I cannot reveal too much about the indexing, since it's a library they wrote. I don't see how the indexing is necessary information for the text extraction though? (EDIT) It's basically sending the object modeled after the mapping to a translator to convert it to an elasticsearch query.

Comment: You wrote: "Whenever I start indexing the files, i get an OutOfMemoryException." I guess Elasticsearch throws this because normally ES does the indexing that's why I asked for more info. BTW 2GB for an ES server is very small, see this: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/hardware.html

Comment: @maestro Sorry for the misunderstanding in the post. When I say 'indexing the files' I really just mean the application running as a whole. The elastic server is not running on the same server as the application. It has its own dedicated server with 8-16gb ram (12 I think?).

Comment: How many threads are running with -Xmx1024m?  In our regression corpus testing for Tika, I try to leave at least 1GB per thread.  Can you reliably get an OOM on specific files with pure Tika (java -Xmx1024m -jar tika-app.jar)?  If so, that _might_ be a bug we can fix.

Comment: @TimAllison There is only 1 Tika instance active at any given time. The rest of the application is also not written multi-threaded, so the files are read and indexed sequentially. Upping the memory seemed to fix it for the most part. Managed to reach about 50k documents with the following JVM settings: `-XX:+AggressiveOpts -XX:+ScavangeBeforeFullGC -XX:-UseG1GC -server -Xms512m -Xmx1500m`. The program was still stopped, but due to a different exception this time (`Exception in thread`).

Comment: According to VisualVM in a test environment, the application has 43 threads (of these 41 Daemon threads). Most of these belong to Spring (boot) / elasticsearch. `main` only has 1 thread, as expected.

Comment: Oh, good.  I interpreted "I am also not well versed in multithreading" as you were running Tika in more than one thread. Because Tika includes a kitchen sink of parsers (which we can't control), it can use a surprising amount of memory and you need to be able to handle: [rare but catastrophic failures](http://events.linuxfoundation.org/sites/events/files/slides/TikaEval_ACNA15_allison_herceg_v2.pdf#page=17).  See our [wiki on tika-batch](http://wiki.apache.org/tika/TikaBatchOverview) and [usage](http://wiki.apache.org/tika/TikaBatchUsage).

Comment: If you find particular files that cause problems, please open a ticket on our [jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/tika).

Comment: Just a quick question (could be Tika): I'm running the application right now. It has reached about 60k documents, but memory is consistently way too high (around 1.5-1.7gb), while it shouldn't do much more than read the document from stream, return text, index text, garbage collect (eventually). Will make thread dump soon, but wondering if you knew of any intricacies that might be caused by Tika concerning memory?

Comment: Y, we are always trying to identify and fix memory issues.  PDFBox 2.0.3 is just out and integrated into Tika trunk, and that fixes some memory issues.  When we upgrade to POI 3.15 in the next few days, that will fix one more.

Comment: but memory is consistently way too high (around 1.5-1.7gb)...this is fairly typical.  In practice, GC won't kick in until you're close to Xmx, so memory will grow and appear higher than it needs to be.  If you set -Xmx to 1g, you'll probably appear to use less, but I'd recommend not setting it so low.